# How to launch a Chromium application using Chromedriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

Is it possible to port this python code to work in Robot Framework?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.binary_location = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/MyApp.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Program Files (x86)/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

I'm trying to create a chrome webdriver in robot that sends my selenium calls to my chromium application. Is it possible?

I create a python Library see code below but it just launches my app and closes it. I want to be able to make selenium/robot calls to it.

Code for myLibrary.py

```
    import selenium
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

    from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

    def pas_webdriver_instance():
    se2lib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('ExtendedSelenium2Library')
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.binary_location = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/myapp.exe'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Program Files (x86)/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: How is this question different from the other question you asked?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply expand `Selenium2Library` and use your Python code directly. To expand `Selenium2Library` you can either make a new class that inherits the original library, or get the runnung library's instance on runtime.

Or, if you absolutely want to port this into Robot Framework, you can try out this keyword:

```
Open Chrome
    [Arguments]    ${url}    ${binary_path}
    ${chrome_options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    binary_location    ${binary_path}
    Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${chrome_options}
    Go To    ${url}
```

**Edit**: To answer your question in comments,

That depends on the version of Selenium2Library you're using since the library got reworked heavily in it's last version, but if you're using versions prior to it's version 3, you can see an example of expansion that gets an instance [here](https://github.com/Selenium2Library/robotframework-angularjs/blob/master/AngularJSLibrary/__init__.py) (see the property `_s2l`), and an example of class inheritance [here](https://github.com/axon-id/Selenium2LibraryExtension/blob/master/src/Selenium2LibraryExtension/__init__.py) (see the declaration of the class).

I haven't looked into expanding the last version of SeleniumLibrary yet so I couldn't tell you for this particular case. Retrieving the library's instance on runtime should still work fine though.

Comment: Thank you so much! If I want to go ahead and expand the Selenium2Library with this python code for binary_location how would this python code look?

Comment: Thank you that is helpful. I'm using the following code but my application just launches and quits. I want to be able to make calls to this application instance once opened like a regular selenium calling a URL.

Comment: I realize this may be beyond my python coding ability but it would be so great to get this to work!